# How to keep image original in QgraphicsView in QT

Tags: image, qt, scale, mousewheel, qgraphicsview

I have load an image in QGraphicsView, but consider of the size of QGraphicsView scene, I need to scale the image first, then add the scaled image to scene. 
e.g. The image original size is 1536*1024, the QGraphicsView size is 500*400, firstly I scale the image like this:

```
image2D = image2D.scaled( h * P , h, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
myScene->setSceneRect((h * P-w)/2, 0, h * P , h);
pixmapItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(image2D);
myScene->addItem(pixmapItem);
myView->setScene(myScene);
```

And now a problem comes to me, when wheelEvent happends and the QGraphicsView zoom in, the scaled image becomes indistinct while I want it to keep as clear as the original one.
I find a way that I can hold an original copy of image, then when wheelEvent happend just scale the original copy and put it to scene. 
But I don't know how to write this code, thanks for help~
or are there any simple methods?

```
class interactiveView : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override;
}
void interactiveView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    int scrollAmount = event->delta();

    xPos = event->pos().x();
    yPos = event->pos().y();

    scrollAmount > 0 ? zoomIn() : zoomOut();
}
```

**Update:**
I find a simple way like this:
just use `QGraphicsView::fitInView()` to make sure that the image scale is equal to QGraphicsView, and do not need to scale image first.
Therefore the image won't be indistinct when zoom in, and I only need to recall the `QGraphicsView::fitInView()` to reset to original view instead of using `QGraphicsView::resetMatrix()`

```
void myImageWindow::loadImag(int w, int h)
{
     pixmapItem->setPixmap(image2D);
    //if the scale of image changed
    if(image2D.height() != imgHeight_pre){
        myView->fitInView(pixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
        imgHeight_pre = image2D.height();
    }
    //if the scene of QGraphicsView changed
    if(h != sceneHeight_pre){
        myView->fitInView(pixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
        sceneHeight_pre = h;
    }
}
void myImageWindow::on_rstImgBtn_clicked()
{
    myView->fitInView(pixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
}
```

Scaled image:

[image: scaled image]

becomes indistinct when zoom in:

[image: becomes indistinct when zoom in]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `resetMatrix()` to reset image

**For example**:

```
graphicsView->scale(2, 2);
graphicsView->resetMatrix();
graphicsView->scale(1, 1);
```

Comment: hi, I find a really simple way like this: `myView->fitInView(pixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);`